# How to conditionally format a date column based on before/after another date?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I have a spreadsheet where each row represents a case, and one column (Column E) is a manually-entered date, whereas numerous columns following are based on Column E plus or minus various spans of time (various deadlines).

I've added Column D, which will be manually entered dates not directly related to Column E.

How can I conditionally format Column D so that it changes if the date manually entered is before versus after one of the dates based on Column E (one of the deadlines)?

I have searched for this but I don't seem to have found an answer to this particular issue *as far as I understand*.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: This question isn't clear.  *"so that it changes if the date manually entered is before versus after **one of the dates based on Column E** (one of the deadlines)?"* You described dates in *"numerous columns following based on Column E plus or minus"*.   What specifically do you mean? It would be helpful if you [edited your question](/posts/165753/edit) to include some sample data and an example of your expected result.

Answer (score 2):

follow these steps:

1. select column `D`
2. choose conditional formatting from the Format menu
3. for green (when `D` is higher than `E`) enter this custom formula: `= D2>E2`
   and select the GREEN fill color
4. for red (when `D` is lower than `E`) enter this custom formula: `= D2<E2` and select the RED fill color

You will get something like this:
[image: cond form]

[test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gP3_t42oeDRehD4Sw2vkXazHysvgiHRb6NSWBb22-Wk/edit?usp=sharing)